# Dynamically Add New Column on Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the PRO Column and CON Column. On the click of a button, I'd like to add a neutral column. The following picture is what I'd like it to look like. I'd very much appreciate guidance on this issue. ‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎
[image]‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ButtonPro").click(function () {
        $("#okay").append("<div class='RowPro'><div class='GreenStripe'></div><div class='InputPro' contenteditable>Input</div></div>");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ButtonCon").click(function () {
        $("#okay2").append("<div class='RowCon' style='left: -231px; position: relative;'><div class='RedStripe'></div><div class='InputCon' contenteditable>Input</div></div>");
    });
});
```

```css
.Rectangle {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 50000px;
  height: 50000px;
  background: #f2f4f5;
}

.Rectangle2 {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 105px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 105px;
  left: 270px;
  top: 280px;
}
.Group{
   pointer-events: none;
}

.Group2{
   pointer-events: none;
}

.Rectangle3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 294px;
  top: 305px;
  background: #1d67ac;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.Zander{
  position: absolute;
  width: 218px;
  height: 39px;
  left: 297px;
  top: 331px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.Rectangle4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 499px;
  height: 65px;
  left: 270px;
  top: 397px;

  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.Pros {
  position: absolute;
  width: 430px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 294px;
  top: 418px;

  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  /* identical to box height, or 150% */

  color: #41cc90;
}

.ButtonPro {
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 721px;
  top: 430px;

  background: #41cc90;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.Group {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 728.5px;
  top: 437px;

  .Vector {
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    left: 728.5px;
    top: 422px;

    background: #ffffff;
  }
}

.Rectangle6 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 65px;
  left: 769px;
  top: 397px;

  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.Rectangle_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 65px;
  left: 766px;
  top: 397px;

  background: #f2f4f5;
}

.Cons {
  position: absolute;
  width: 430px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 794px;
  top: 418px;

  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  /* identical to box height, or 150% */

  color: #ff725c;
}

.ButtonCon {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #ff725c;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 1222px;
  top: 430px;
  background: #ff725c;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.Group2 {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 1229px;
  top: 437px;

  .Vector2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    left: 1230px;
    top: 422px;

    background: #ffffff;
  }
}

.RowPro {
  width: 496px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.GreenStripe {
  position: relative;
  width: 95px;
  height: 8px;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
  background: #41cc90;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.InputPro {
  width: 500px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  left: 16px;
  top: 33px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #2C343D;
}

.RowCon {
  width: 496px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.RedStripe {
  position: relative;
  width: 95px;
  height: 8px;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
  background: #FF725C;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.InputCon {

  
  width: 500px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  left: 16px;
  top: 33px;

  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
/* identical to box height, or 150% */


  color: #2C343D;
}


#okay{
  position: absolute;
  width: 496px;
  height: 123px;
  left: 270px;
  top: 479px;
}


#okay2{
  position: absolute;
  width: 496px;
  max-height: 123px;
  left: 1000px;
  top: 479px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lol">
    <p class="Rectangle"></p>
    <p class="Rectangle2"></p>
    <p class="Zander" contenteditable> Pro Con:</p>
    <p class="Rectangle3"></p>
    <p class="Rectangle4"></p>
    <p class="Rectangle4"></p>
    <p class="Pros" contenteditable>Pros</p>
    <p class="Pros" contenteditable>Pros</p>
    <button id="ButtonPro" class="ButtonPro"></button>

    <button id="ButtonPro" class="ButtonPro"></button>

    <div class="Group">
        <div class="Vector">
            <svg width="18" height="17" viewBox="0 0 18 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M11.125 6.375V0H6.875V6.375H0.5V10.625H6.875V17H11.125V10.625H17.5V6.375H11.125Z" fill="white" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p class="Rectangle6"></p>

    <p class="Rectangle_1"></p>

    <p class="Cons" contenteditable>Cons</p>

    <button id="ButtonCon" class="ButtonCon"></button>

    <div class="Group2">
        <div class="Vector2">
            <svg width="18" height="17" viewBox="0 0 18 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M11.125 6.375V0H6.875V6.375H0.5V10.625H6.875V17H11.125V10.625H17.5V6.375H11.125Z" fill="white" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="okay">
        <div class="RowPro">
            <div class="GreenStripe"></div>
            <div class="InputPro" contenteditable>Input</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="Rectangle_2"></p>

    <div id="okay2">
        <div class="RowCon" style="left: -231px; position: relative;">
            <div class="RedStripe"></div>
            <div class="InputCon" contenteditable>Input</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</div>
```

Comment: *I'd very much appreciate guidance on this issue.* <-- What is the "issue" you are having? What ***specific*** problem are you asking about? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Comparing the code versus the picture, there is an added column. It is my desire to dynamically add new columns, a neutral column for example, on the click of a button. @ScottMarcus

Comment: Stack Overflow answers don't usually give general help implementing an entire feature, but instead resolve specific problems that come up during the implementation of the feature. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: You haven’t stated a specific problem you are having. You’re describing a feature you want to implement.